# angular xml 2 json service splitting nodes on fullstop

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, xml

I'm using the following angular service to convert my xml to json:
[angular-xml2json](https://github.com/sammychl/angular-xml2json)

This has worked fine for me converting my simple xml to json however if i include a fullstop it breaks the current node it's on. so for example:

```
<title>hello</title>
<description>This is a description with a fullstop. And so on.</description>
```

the above would return:

```
{ title: "hello" }
{ description: "this is a description with a fullstop" }
```

I cant really understand why an xml2json converter would modify the values of nodes, but it appears to be doing just that.

I took a deeper look into the service to see if i could spot what was causing this, and i feel this is the issue:

```
xml_to_object: function(xmlcode) {
    var x = xmlcode.replace(/<\//g, ".");
    x = x.split("<");
    var y = [];
    var level = 0;
    var opentags = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < x.length; i++) {
        var tagname = x[i].split(">")[0];
        opentags.push(tagname);
        level++
        y.push(level + "<" + x[i].split(".")[0]);
        while (x[i].indexOf("." + opentags[opentags.length - 1] + ">") >= 0) {
            level--;
            opentags.pop()
        }
    };
```

I was hoping someone has had this issue and solved it, or someone smarter than me can help out. I believe the above code is finding instances of `</` and replacing it with `.` which obviously means if you have any fullstops in your values such as a `file.jpeg` or punctuation its creating a new node.

Comment: I think you have an old version, check it hasn't that code anymore: https://github.com/sammychl/angular-xml2json/blob/master/angular-xml2json.js

Comment: @Michelem you are right they are different.. but i swear there is only one version 0.0.1 strange..

Comment: That's a forgetfulness by the author, he had to change the version but I think he forgot that. Just uninstall your local directory of angular-xml2json and reinstalll it.

Comment: @Michelem whenever i remove it and re-install it, i get the old the version, it's like it cant see the version we can (even if i just change it to use the github url).. any suggestions?

Comment: Try this `bower install 'git://github.com/sammychl/angular-xml2json#69fe1806790ae00ea94c6e4d9a187695c85a2782'`

Comment: just says ENOTFOUND Package 'git://github.com/sammychl/angular-xml2json not found

Comment: @Michelem I asked the author to update his package thankfully he did, so it's all good thanks for your help